# Tasm include files

Tags: assembly, tasm

I wrote a simple "Hello world" program in assembly, and i want to include an .inc file there. how to do this?

```
include "windows.inc"
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
HelloMessage DB 'Hello, world',13,10,'$'

CODESEG

start:
    mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax ;set DS to point to the data segment
mov ah,9 ;DOS print string function
mov dx,OFFSET HelloMessage ;point to "Hello, world"
int 21h ;display "Hello, world"
exit:
mov ah,4ch ;DOS terminate program function
int 21h ;terminate the program
END start
```

error: Code cannot be assembled. One or more support file for this assembly code is missing.

Comment: "windows.inc" is likely something that comes from MASM32 and won't work with TASM in 16-bit code.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    .386

    .model flat, stdcall

    include user32.inc
    include kernel32.inc
    include WINDOWS.INC

    .data
    MsgBoxCaption  db "Win32 app",0
    MsgBoxText     db "Hi User!",0

    .code
    start:
         invoke MessageBox, NULL, ADDR MsgBoxText, ADDR MsgBoxCaption, MB_OK
         invoke ExitProcess, NULL
    end start
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! We like answers that give details about the cause of the problem, even in a minimalistic way - we try to avoid code only answers. The OP is confusing two operating systems - you picked up Windows over DOS which may or may not be what the OP intended, always state your assumptions. Finally, this display a message box, Windows can easily display a message on a console as well. Consider converting the example into a console one or ask the OP for more information.